# Titanium.Media.showCamera with overlay, pass through events

Tags: javascript, iphone, view, titanium, appcelerator

I am writing an iOS application that utilizes the camera. I want an image (and ultimately a control element or two) overlayed over the camera picture.

This already works. However the overlay prevents the default control elements for Flash, HDR and camera selection from receiving touch events.

Below is my code. Is there a way to make myOverlay pass through or ignore events?

```
var overlayImage = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundImage: 'img/picture.png'
});
var myOverlay = Titanium.UI.createView();
myOverlay.add(overlayImage);

Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success: successMethod,
    error: errorMethod,
    cancel: function(e) {},
    overlay: myOverlay,
    saveToPhotoGallery: true,
    allowEditing: false,
    mediaTypes: ['public.image']
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `var myOverlay = Titanium.UI.createView({touchEnabled: false});` and it should pass events according to the Appcelerator docs.

Comment: If you disable touch events on the view, how will your newly added control elements recieve touch data?

Comment: Ash you wouldn't disable it if you wanted controls, but a img overlay like above you don't want disabling your camera controls